# OLED Brightness fix at startup

Tags: scripts, dell, startup, brightness

I am actually new in the ubuntu world so I am actually stuck in a easy issue, I guess (?)

I own a dell 7590 xps 15, it has got an oled panel and the brightness slider does not work
I found a script to fix this and make the Fn brigh_up and down work (even if the slider still wont work)
but i have to execute the script at every startup
I d like to know if there is a way to do this auto

I am on ubuntu 19, i have seen the rc.local way

So I added the script path + acpid reload (otherwise it wont work)
but nothing.. I guess that the script works but the reload wont because it needs sudo

indeed if as soon as ubuntu boots i type "sudo acpid reload" the brightness keys work both of them, so i guess that the scipt has worked but the reload has not
thank you very much for your help..

Comment: `lsb_release -rd` please.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 Release 19.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's a little late, but I just finished implementing it and I think you'll love it.

This answer will unstuck you, but probably not the way you intended to be unstuck, but better. Doing OLED brightness changes with ACPI hooks is simply a compromise. If you change the brightness instantly, you compromise smooth brightness changes, if you do smooth brightness changes, you compromise reliability (because now you can press the function key twice before the previous changes apply and thus get flickering), and night light is simply not supported, because the "color correction" is updated only when you press the brightness keys.

[This repository](https://github.com/lawleagle/oled-linux) is a much better solution for both your slider and your startup issues. And now you can have night light too :)

It works by watching for changes in brightness (the normal brightness you adjust using your slider or whatever normal method you use) and applying them to the OLED panel. It does require a little tweaking, but it's worth it.

After switching to this solution, I noticed the nice dimming effects my desktop environment provides when I'm away from my laptop for a while, and also the brightness fade effects on the lockscreen. These are little things that you can't get with ACPI hooks

Comment: Thank you very mich for your suggestion.. I have tried to clone it and make this file but I did not managed to, unluckyly I am new to linux and I had never heard of this

Comment: There is no need for make, it's just shell scripts. A quick way to see if it works for you or not is to manually run oled-linux.sh and then change the brightness in whatever way you want.

Also, feel free to drop by in the discord group of the project (you can find that in the Community section of the README) and if not me, somebody will help you in as much detail as you need

Comment: actually I was so dumb, I did not know what i3 was (the window manager) and I thought that was something difficult or that I did not know, actually works GREAT. I used a systemd service, and one suggestion, I had to set brightness step to 1000, indeed I thought the script was not working, so I tried with an echo and lookup for the percent var, I actually saw this shifting up and down if I used brightness keys or the slider. So I saw that it needed around 15 minutes from min to max brightness vice versa and I understood that the step was way too few.. maybe a comment would help some else

Comment: I thought that a well written and working scripts for oled displays did not exist, this definitely needs an advertise in some forums/subreddits (exp. Dell and Lenovo owners) edit: I went in difficulty because I thought i3 was something that I had to do

Comment: I do not manage to just edit comments, if on the README there would be a noob-config how to, like adding the gnome autostart entry, this is how I did, for instance https://pastebin.com/44N8xnvR Thank you again for this script!

Comment: Well, of course you did not know about it, I finished writing it just before telling you. Also, I posted about it on /r/linux and it was quite well-received. There are still a bunch more forum threads I want to reply to, just to grow awareness.

Brightness step is machine-dependent, so any default value will be inconvenient for some users. I chose 12 because that's a good value for the X1 Yoga, which is the most popular OLED laptop at the moment. Good news is that it can be calculated and taken out of the config, but that is for sometime in the future.

Comment: It feels amazing to finally do something for people, I learned lot from the internet, and now it's time to give back, so if you enjoy my work, don't forget to star and follow on GitHub and thumbs up wherever you liked :)

Comment: Already starred! Unluckyly I can not upvote on this forum yet